# USB Devices stop working randomly in Windows 10, Event 3 usbehci

Tags: windows-10, usb

My computer has been having a problem where randomly any USB port that I have a device connected to will stop working. There are a couple ways of temporarily fixing this: Plug all USB devices into a previously unused port, or restart my computer.

I've done some research, and though many people have this problem, I can't seem to find a fix that works for me. I've tried reinstalling the drivers for all my USB devices, reinstalling Windows updates, hell I even reinstalled Windows 10 entirely and this problem is still present.

The only thing I can find on my system is an error in the System logs which is as follows:

`Event 3, usbehci;
A timeout occurred while waiting for the EHCI host controller Asynchronous Schedule to transition to the enabled state.`

This error keeps being logged, once to twice every minute after the USB ports stop working. It seems to be the cause as well, but I can't find a fix.

Windows 10 Home, MSI 970A Gaming Pro Carbon MOBO, 1x8GB Kingston HyperX Fury 1866MHz RAM, AMD FX-8350 CPU, 850W power supply, GTX 7xx something Ti video card.

I recently replaced my motherboard. And CPU. And RAM. The problem started to occur after I replaced all this (about 2 weeks ago). The latest bios is the only bios, though I still tried to update it to what it already was. And as far as I know, it happens regardless of what's plugged in.

The previous motherboard was some ASUS AI Lifestyle, CPU Intel, various speeds and brands of ram. I don't have them anymore so that's the best I can do.

Comment: Is this a new problem, or has this machine always had this problem?  Are you running the latest firmware/BIOS for that motherboard?  Does it matter which USB devices are plugged in?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I forgot to say in the post, but I recently replaced my motherboard. And CPU. And RAM. The problem started to occur after I replaced all this (about 2 weeks ago). The latest bios is the only bios, though I still tried to update it to what it already was. And as far as I know, it happens regardless of what's plugged in. Testing it would basically sit around for 10 hours with one thing plugged into the computer, and hope the error occurs. It only happens occasionally. Sometimes multiple times in one day, sometimes a few days will pass before the next time it happens.

Comment: The 970 is AMD platform. And what kind of board it was before? Did you completely re-install the Windows after hardware upgrade?

Comment: @Coarse Edit your question

Comment: I'm getting this issue, too. Did you ever find a solution to the problem? I'm thinking of getting another USB card to plug into the motherboard, in case it's an issue specific to the onboard USB ports.

Comment: @Simon East, if I recall correctly (3 years is a while), this issue was caused by the usb port's bandwidth. I was using a usb 2 port for my wifi adapter, which seemed to crash the driver or something when I downloaded large amounts of data. I fixed this issue by putting anything that requires a lot of usb bandwidth through usb 3.0 ports. I got more for my motherboard through a usb 3.0 card, and that seems to have fixed it in the years since.